# Cmd+Tab with arrow keys

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut

So, I used to be able to cycle through apps back and forth by holding <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> while pressing <kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> arrow keys. I can't now that I've done a fresh install of Sierra. What happens now is when I press the arrow keys, the next or previous program opens up. I can't cycle anymore. Only tab does that now, and just in one direction.

I tried searching the net, hoping that there's just something in the preferences that I missed, but nothing close to it comes out. Help?

Comment: In reference to tab only going one direction, you can shift-tab whilst holding cmd to go left

Comment: Additionally, you can go left by pressing the back-tick (`) key while still holding the command key after pressing command+tab.

Comment: @grgarside Thanks for the shift-tab! It feels quite uncomfortable, but at least it's an alternative.

Comment: @AJ. Thanks for this too! Unfortunately though, it also works like the left arrow key now. Once I press it, it opens up the previous window and doesn't let me cycle through in an opposite direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can cycle through open applications by holding the <kbd>Command</kbd> key and tapping (but not holding) the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

As long as <kbd>Command</kbd> remains pressed you can use the <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd> keys to cycle through open applications.